# Moving an object to another process

Tags: python, ipc, rpc

I'm working with a piece of hardware that must be stopped and started at different intervals. Unfortunately, it doesn't teardown gracefully, so restarting within the  same process results in libusb errors. One workaround would be to move the configuration of the hardware to a different process, and stop/start the process when required.

What would be the best way to do this in Python?

Comment: Have a gander at the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. Particularly the section on [`Queues` and `Pipes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module allows you to serialize objects to a string, so you can transfer it via the disk or a socket.

You could also use [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), which is intended for parallelism, but could be used here too. (Actually, `multiprocessing` relies on `pickle`.)